Can I use mantine UI in requireJS?
I have a project using ReactBootstrap like this in requireJS
"ReactBootstrap": "vendor/react-bootstrap.min",

If my understanding is correct, I would need a .js file in order to use the library?
I would like to switch to mantine UI as its Form module have something I like.
What do I need to do to use mantine UI instead? Or is it even possible? Is it something about webpacks?
